# maven-war-plugin process multibyte filename incorrectly

Tags: maven

My project has some resource files with multibyte filename(Japanese characters). 
I found that maven can process those files until war:exploded task correctly. But 
after executed war:war task, those files' name was broken in created war file.

I had tried ant task(jar, war), there is no problem. And more , I found this link:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/xref/org/apache/maven/plugin/war/packaging/AbstractWarPackagingTask.html#213

But I guess this problem caused by ZipOutputStream or JarOutputStream. Could anyone
give me an advice? I don't want to use maven-antrun-plugin.

By the way, I use Oracle JDK 1.6.0_31 and Maven 3.0.4.

my maven-war-plugin version is 2.1.1. Further more, I tried maven-antrun-plugin and 
got the same result.

By the way, my question is the multibyte filename broken, not the file content.
I filter resource files with resource plugin and there's no problem.

Comment: Which version of maven-war-plugin do you use? Have you set the encoding? Are you doing some kind of filtering?

Comment: I've see other folks with this issue; I have a feeling it's a bug

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-archiver</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-container-default</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-component-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```